# Inconsistency in validating the required comment length

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

On Stack Overflow, while adding a comment, there is a label showing information about the required content length under the comment text box.

If I type "If I type!", the label says "5 more to go" or so,  I can add spaces to the end until the text changes to "585 characters left".

So I can now submit my comment, but if I do, I get the error message "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length".

One would expect spaces to be ignored or considered by both validators.

Comment: Maybe it is a feature (and not a bug) because SE team probably wants to annoy those who find petty ways to "game" the system :)

Comment: Probably KISS applies here, too. Being exact just to be exact does not warant the added complexity.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design: [Comment character counter does not trim, while the server does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98970/comment-character-counter-does-not-trim-while-the-server-does)

> We view this as intentionally gaming the character count, so my answer is "don't do that".